# Google Developer Registration doesn't work

Tags: android, google-play, registration, playback

I've tried to create Google Developer account several times but without success.

I've created new e-mail and also setup Google pay account with my credit card.

When I go to Google Developer Registration page: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/

and I sign in as new account that I've created and try to pay nothing happens.

In popup where I clicked pay shows up little reloading icon for about 1-2 seconds and then disappear while popup is still the same. At my google pay account there is no any activity and I didn't get any error on registration page.

Is there anyone with same problem? Also I contacted google support but still no help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming